# Overloading, Referencing, and everything in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is a big one and I apologize.

I am practicing to make my coding more modular.
We are tasked to create a Shipyard system.
There are Containers in the Shipyard and Packages in the Containers.

There is a LinkedList program provided that can be imported. I added it on the bottom.

IMPORTANT: I CANNOT ALTER THE SORTED LINKED LIST PROGRAM IN ANY WAY HENCE WHY I USE OVERLOADERS

I have another program which is non-modular. It is specifically made for the assignment at hand and it works for the most part.

Python 3.5

```
from SortedLList import *

class Shipyard:
    def __init__(self):
        self._container = SortedLList()

    def add(self, owner, destination, weight):
        """
        This function does:
        1. Adds a container for a specific destination if doesn't exist.
        2. Adds a package in a container given that the total weight 
        doesn't exceed 2000 lbs
        3. If it does, it creates another container headed in the same
        direction and then the package is inserted there instead.
        """
        self._container.insert(Self.Container(destination))

    class Container:
        def __init__(self, destination):
            self._package = SortedLList()
            self._dest = destination
            self._weight = 0
            self._max = 2000

       def add_pack(self, owner, destination, weight):
           """
           This function adds the weight of the package to the total
           container weight. And inserts a Package Singly Linked List
           object inside the container.
           """
           self._weight += weight
           self._package.insert(Self.Package(destination))

       def __lt__(self, other):
           return self._dest < other._dest

       def __ge__(self, other):
           return self._dest >= other._dest

       def __eq__(self, other):
           return self._dest == other._dest

       class Package:
           def __init__(self, owner, destination, weight):
               self._owner = owner
               self._dest = destination
               self._weight = weight

           def __lt__(self, other):
               return self._weight < other._weight

           def __ge__(self, other):
               return self._weight >= other._weight

           def __eq__(self, other):
              return self._weight == other._weight


class SortedLList :
    class _Node :
        def __init__(self, elem, next) :
            self._elem = elem
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self) :
        self._first = None
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self) :
        return self._size

    def isEmpty(self) :
        return len(self) == 0

    def first(self):
        return self._elem._first

    def insert(self, val) :  
        if (self.isEmpty() or val <self._first._elem):
            self._size+=1
        self._first = self._Node(val,self._first)

        tmpRef=self._first

        while(tmpRef._next!=None and val>=tmpRef._next._elem):
            tmpRef=tmpRef._next

        if val==tmpRef._elem:
            return
        self._size+=1
        tmpRef._next=self._Node(val,tmpRef._next)
        return

    def isPresent(self, elem) :
        tmpRef=self._first
        while(tmpRef!=None):
            if tmpRef._elem==elem:
                return True
            tmpRef=tmpRef._next
        return False

    def delete(self, elem) :
        if self.isEmpty() :
            return
        if elem == self._first._elem :
            self._size -= 1
            self._first = self._first._next
            return

        tmpRef = self._first
        while (tmpRef._next != None and elem > tmpRef._next._elem) :
            tmpRef = tmpRef._next

        if tmpRef._next == None : return

        if tmpRef._next._elem != elem : return

        self._size -= 1
        tmpRef._next = tmpRef._next._next
        return


    def traversePrint(self) :
        tmpRef = self._first
        while tmpRef != None :
            print(tmpRef._elem)
            tmpRef = tmpRef._next

    class Empty(Exception) :
        pass
```

I want to be able to use the methods in the SortedLList program to be able to display information that I have in the main program.

Is there any way around typing:
print(self._cont._first._elem._dest) or print(self._cont._first._elem._package._first._elem._owner) by using traversePrint() without altering the helper code?

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit SortedLList in a new class and overload the methods you want.

```
class MySortedLList(SortedLList):
    def traversePrint(self):
        # Your custom implementation
```

and then using that instead of SortedLLIst, e.g:

```
class Shipyard:
    def __init__(self):
        self._container = MySortedLList()
```

However,, you asked if you can use the `SortedLList.traversePrint` to print information about your main program, presumable `Shipyard`. This probably doesn't make sense because you'd break encapsulation. `SortedLList` knows about its elements and can only know about `Shipyard` if you give it a reference to `Shipyard`. So rather let `Shipyard` tell you about itself.

Comment: I see what you did here and I can make it work like that but how would I do it without changing or inheriting SortedLList into a class?

I am also lost on how to implement the add functions and how to overload the __eq__.


In Container __eq__ should also check if the weight of the incoming package + the container weight doesn't go over 2000.  And if so it should add the package to that same container. (I can do this sacrificing modularity but that goes against the point)


In Package __eq__ has to add the package despite similarities in weight.